# Apache Cordova Facebook Plugin (latest version/current master) crashes my android app while initializing

Tags: android, facebook, apache, cordova, plugins

I've created the sample app given in the latest version (current master) of Apache Cordova Facebook Plugin several times:

https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-facebook-plugin

Currently, I'm working on Android only.

The first time I created this sample app (about two weeks ago) everything worked fine. I successfully logged in with my facebook account, posted a status to my wall and logged out (all the other actions worked fine as well).

But since than I've created this sample app several more times (in the exact same way), and it has never worked again (the last time I tried was today). In the new apps (with the very same code as the first app, which still works), I press "LOGIN WITH FACEBOOK", and my app crashes immediately. Sometimes the app doesn't crash immediately, and I can get the message "Argument 'session' cannot be null". Then I press "LOGIN WITH FACEBOOK" again, and the app crashes. Sometimes I can get this message several times before the app eventually crashes.
If I press "LOGOUT WITH FACEBOOK", I get the message: "No valid session found, must call init and login before logout".

I also don't think that the problem is that I have a wrong hash key or something like that, because I've been careful with the settings of the facebook app every time.

I also believe that I've installed the plugin correctly each time, because I've always done it the same way I did it the first time, which worked fine.

So how is it that in my latest attempts the session variable is NULL??
Why did it work only in the first time??
I'm very frustrated..

**Edit:**

Here is the relevant segment of the LogCat log:

```
D/ConnectPlugin( 7064): login FB

W/dalvikvm( 7064): VFY: unable to resolve static field 2130 (com_facebook_internet_permission_error_title) in Lcom/facebook/android/R$string;

D/dalvikvm( 7064): VFY: replacing opcode 0x60 at 0x0010

I/dalvikvm( 7064): DexOpt: unable to optimize static field ref 0x0851 at 0x18 in Lcom/facebook/AuthorizationClient;.checkInternetPermission

W/dalvikvm( 7064): VFY: unable to resolve static field 2120 (com_facebook_login_activity_layout) in Lcom/facebook/android/R$layout;

D/dalvikvm( 7064): VFY: replacing opcode 0x60 at 0x0003

W/dalvikvm( 7064): VFY: unable to resolve static field 2103 (com_facebook_login_activity_progress_bar) in Lcom/facebook/android/R$id;

D/dalvikvm( 7064): VFY: replacing opcode 0x60 at 0x0008

I/ActivityManager( 2112): START {intent.toShortString} from pid 7064

I/power   ( 2112): *** acquire_dvfs_lock : lockType : 1  freq : 1000000 

D/PowerManagerService( 2112): acquireDVFSLockLocked : type : DVFS_MIN_LIMIT  frequency : 1000000  uid : 1000  pid : 2112  tag : ActivityManager

W/ActivityManager( 2112): mDVFSLock.acquire()

D/dalvikvm( 7064): GC_CONCURRENT freed 455K, 6% free 12931K/13639K, paused 4ms+5ms

W/PluginManager( 7064): THREAD WARNING: exec() call to FacebookConnectPlugin.login blocked the main thread for 207ms. Plugin should use CordovaInterface.getThreadPool().

D/CordovaActivity( 7064): Paused the application!

D/CordovaWebView( 7064): Handle the pause

D/FirewallPolicy( 2112): getURLFilterEnabled(true)

D/FirewallPolicy( 2112): isUrlBlocked - Policy disabled

D/webkit  ( 7064): Firewall not null

D/FirewallPolicy( 2112): getURLFilterEnabled(true)

D/FirewallPolicy( 2112): isUrlBlocked - Policy disabled

I/ClipboardServiceEx( 2112): mCBPickerDialog enter case. MSG_DISMISS_DIALOG

D/webkit  ( 7064): euler: isUrlBlocked = false

D/FirewallPolicy( 2112): getURLFilterEnabled(true)

D/FirewallPolicy( 2112): isUrlBlocked - Policy disabled

D/ActivityManager( 2112): Trying to launch applicationName

D/KeyguardViewMediator( 2112): setHidden false

I/ClipboardServiceEx( 2112): mCBPickerDialog enter case. MSG_DISMISS_DIALOG

D/AndroidRuntime( 7064): Shutting down VM

W/dalvikvm( 7064): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40c6c1f8)

E/AndroidRuntime( 7064): FATAL EXCEPTION: main

E/AndroidRuntime( 7064): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.facebook.android.R$layout

E/AndroidRuntime( 7064):    at com.facebook.LoginActivity.onCreate(LoginActivity.java:57)

E/AndroidRuntime( 7064):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4562)

E/AndroidRuntime( 7064):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1053)

E/AndroidRuntime( 7064):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1934)

E/AndroidRuntime( 7064):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1995)

E/AndroidRuntime( 7064):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:128)

E/AndroidRuntime( 7064):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1161)

E/AndroidRuntime( 7064):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)

E/AndroidRuntime( 7064):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)

E/AndroidRuntime( 7064):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4514)

E/AndroidRuntime( 7064):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)

E/AndroidRuntime( 7064):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)

E/AndroidRuntime( 7064):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:993)

E/AndroidRuntime( 7064):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:760)

E/AndroidRuntime( 7064):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

W/ActivityManager( 2112):   Force finishing activity com.yomama.test/com.facebook.LoginActivity

W/ActivityManager( 2112):   Force finishing activity com.yomama.test/.Test
```

Another strange thing that happened to me yesterday was that I recompiled and re-installed (on my phone) the first working app, and suddenly it didn't work either (I got the same message after pressing "LOGIN WITH FACEBOOK", and then the app crashed). Then I recompiled and re-installed the app again, and it was working fine again. Weird.

Comment: Post your LogCat Log please, if it is an native problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following steps (from [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-facebook-plugin/issues/436); had worked for me):

```
+### Android Setup without Eclipse (just CLI)

+Follow the steps above:

cordova create myApp

cd myApp/

cordova platform add android

cordova -d plugin add https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-facebook-plugin.git --variable APP_ID="123456789" --variable APP_NAME="myApplication"

// add FacebookLib

echo "android.library.reference.2=com.phonegap.plugins.facebookconnect/FacebookLib" >> platforms/android/project.properties

cp platforms/android/local.properties platforms/android/com.phonegap.plugins.facebookconnect/FacebookLib

android update project -p platforms/android/

cd platforms/android/

ant clean

cd com.phonegap.plugins.facebookconnect/FacebookLib

ant clean

open -e AndroidManifest.xml

// change your minSdkVersion and your targetSdkVersion to your environment settings.

ant release

cd ../../../..

cordova build android

With this steps you can add the Plugin without using Eclipse
```

Comment: it worked for me by appending "com.phonegap.plugins.facebookconnect" to FacebookLib path